# Python search folder and make a Dictionary

Tags: python

I need to make a Dictionary out of some folder hierachy.

I have a folder in /home/Desktop/songs --- inside there are   Folder: "A" and another "B". Inside of folder A and B there are folder: "1" and "2"

I want to get the FOLDERS inside "songs" and get the folders inside A and B .
Then make a Dictionary with them. Like THIS:

```
A={'1','2'}
B={'1','2'}
```

That way,  If I update my folders the script gets updated.

I started looking to something like this:

```
os.chdir('/home/Desktop/songs')
letter = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
print letter
-----> A,B
```

But I dont know how to  append them  in a dictionary.

Comment: It would save some time if you described what went wrong when you ran your code.

Comment: So you want the resultant dictionary to be `{"A": ["1", "2"], "B": ["1", "2"]}`?

Comment: Why not use `os.walk()` instead each time your script runs? It'll recurse over the directories for you.

Comment: And your problem is..?

Comment: @izuriel I believe the OP wants them to be stored in two separate variables.

Comment: My problem is how to get all to work in a Dictionary so I can query the information of the folders  inside of  my script.

Comment: @Asad Yea I'm just trying to work out the details of exactly what he wants. I don't see anything that has to do with a dictionary in his sample (which is why I asked).

Comment: I would like to be able to call  this function afterwards print A.values()-- and get the subfolder names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the descendants of the folders under /home/Desktop/songs, you just need to iterate over the children of the folders you have identified using your comprehension. As a simple example, (although you probably want to make this more readable by using a proper loop):

```
import os

os.chdir('/home/Desktop/songs')
letter = {d : [child 
                  for child in os.listdir('./' + d) 
                  if os.path.isdir('./' + d)
              ] 
              for d in os.listdir('.') 
              if os.path.isdir(d)
         }
print letter
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['1', '2']}
```